# Making application work normally when user turns off screen android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

I'm working on an application that which is media player.

**Question:** How do I make media player (application) work without issues from turning the screen off?
**Question:** loadInBackground() returns the uri but onLoadFinished not called when screen off.

Few words to explain trouble better:

The media player contains `Loader` which loads the song and another `Loader` which loads related suggestions. I've also implemented the method to `play_next()` which relies on a listener of media player on finished (button in right upper corner).

[image]

The media player is initialized in the service class which I've made so the user can search new songs, and prepare the `next_song()` with the button (and the playing continues because I connect to service each time `Activity` is loaded and I return from service media player so I can attach listener for `onFinish` method).

The thing that bothers me is that when the user turns off the screen, the activity goes to idle state (status from android monitor - log cat) and once in idle state (aka *turned off screen*) if the song ends, it will start new intent which is media player to start initializing and auto-playing song. It works when the screen is on but it doesn't if it goes to idle state.

If I turn on the screen I get activity to act like this:

[image]

Little pink dot is a progress bar. So the activity tries to refresh itself? 
In the `onCreate()` method I call `start_loader` which initializes and does the things with `Loader`.

I've seen some power manager tools and seen the bad comments about it which imply to the battery usage but I did try it and from log cat it just went to idle state again (if it matters).

### Help please, maybe if I override `onPause()` Activity and `onResume()`?

Also i get message from loadInBackground() which is uri from song and from there on it freezes doesn't continue.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create `Service` for that that run on Background.so when you play song don'tstop if you keep you screen off.[Service in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

upper link perfectly describe service.

example of service ...

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.divyesh.musiclite.Pojos.SongsList;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Divyesh on 11/18/2017.
 */

public class MediaSongServiece extends Service {
    SongsList s;
    private static Boolean destroy = false;
    private String TAG = "HELLO";
    private MusicIntentReceiver reciever;
    private SharedPreferences prefrence;
    private static MediaPlayer player;
    private int thisStartId = 1;
    private String ss[];
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    public static void requestPlayMedia() {
        player.start();
    }

    public void requestPauseMedia() {
        player.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        reciever = new MusicIntentReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        registerReceiver(reciever, filter);
        Log.d("service", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        stopSelf(thisStartId);
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        if (intent.equals(null)) {
            stopSelf();
        }
        if (destroy == false) {
            thisStartId = startId;
            ss = intent.getExtras().getStringArray("getArray");
            Log.e(TAG, "onStart: " + ss[0] + ss[1] + "    path" + ss[5]);
            s = new SongsList();
            s.setAll(ss);
            if (player != null) {
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(new File(s.getPath())));
                    player.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.setVolume(100, 100);
                player.start();

                Log.e(TAG, "onStart: m= is  not null" + player.isPlaying());
            } else {

                player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(new File(s.getPath())));
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.setVolume(100, 100);
                player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();

                    }
                });
                Log.e(TAG, "onStart: m= is  null WE created new player");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onelse destroy ");
            recover();
        }
    }

    private void recover() {
        destroy = false;
        prefrence = getSharedPreferences("SongPrefrence", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            ss[i] = prefrence.getString("" + i, "");
        }
        String currentPose = prefrence.getString("current_pos", "");

        Log.e(TAG, "recover: Shared Daata is" + ss[5] + "_______" + currentPose);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        unregisterReceiver(reciever);
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        stopSelf(thisStartId);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            prefrence = getSharedPreferences("SongPrefrence", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = prefrence.edit();
            destroy = true;
        }
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            prefrence = getSharedPreferences("SongPrefrence", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = prefrence.edit();
            destroy = true;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void saveData() {
        player.pause();
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            editor.putString("" + i, ss[i]);
        }
        editor.putString("current_pos", "" + player.getCurrentPosition());
        editor.commit();
    }

    public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public String TAG = "ss";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
                switch (state) {
                    case 0:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
                        Toast.makeText(context, " Headset is unpluged ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: " + " is play song " + player.isPlaying());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i do use service beacues of its beneffits i mentioned, but can you be more specific which functionality to implement? New service, separated from media player service?

Comment: wait i can show you a demo of  media player in service. as way you can impleament yours.

Comment: that would be perfecto :D

Comment: it helps you or not?

Comment: trying to figure out your code, so far i've noticed you are calling recover method if landscape is changed (setting bool to true) but you share prefference to song list? as if you were trrying to save the state of that related terms? If that is so my problem is actually the opposite, when the media player ends it starts new intent (loads up), and stops. When i turn on screen it continues to load player, auto playing and loading related

Comment: Luka Modric take list list send to service so it plays  all songs from list . and you have create listner so if list updates it gives you  updated list so you play songs from list

Comment: Sounds like a workaround haha will try it. But when the next song plays the mediaplayer screen should have different results of related terms and then i think it wouldnt play the next one. The UI or the onLoadFinished waits for screen to be turned on so it can load. I wouldnt' be able to reach related songs coz in onLoadFinished i call next loader to load related songs